# angularJS: sorting table with ngTable not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I tried to look around and I found more questions that look the same to this one but no one done it the way I do it, for some reason it doesn't work...

here is the angular code,

```
var myAPP = angular.module('myAPP', ['ngTable']);
myAPP.run(function($rootScope, $http, $moment) {

    $rootScope.items = [];
    $rootScope.currentEvent = "";

    // inital stats - items
    $http.get("/wp-content/themes/theme/myjson.php", {
        params: {
            getAll: true,
            watcherID: <?=get_current_user_id()?>
        }
    }).then(function(reponse) {
        $rootScope.items = reponse.data;
    });


    $rootScope.update = function(inital) {

        $rootScope.items = [];

        $http.get("/wp-content/themes/theme/myjson.php", {
            params: {
                sort: true,
                watcherID: <?=get_current_user_id()?>,
                event: $rootScope.currentEvent
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            $rootScope.items = response.data;
            console.log("data", $rootScope.currentEvent, $rootScope.items);

        });

    } // end update

    $rootScope.$watch('items', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if(!newValue) return;
        if(newValue != oldValue) {
            $rootScope.items = newValue;
            console.log('new value $rootScope.items', $rootScope.items);
        }
    });


});

myAPP.controller('tbleCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, ngTableParams) {
    $scope.data = $rootScope.items;
    $rootScope.$watch('items', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if(!newValue) return;
        if(newValue != oldValue) {
            $scope.data = $rootScope.items;
        }
    });
});
```

first I tried to use the rootScope to handle stuff but after that I tried also to put it in a scope (I thought it i'd make the difference to put the values on var named `data` as all the examples) but I had no luck wit that also.

and this is my controller

```
<div ng-controller="tbleCtrl">
  <table ng-table show-filter="true" class="floodPostTable">
    <tr>
        <th sortable="number">number</th>
        <th sortable="roadNumber">Road number<br /></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
        <td><div ng-show="item.number != false">{{ item.number }}</div></td>
        <td><div ng-show="item.roadNumber != false">{{ item.roadNumber }}</div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

if anyone can direct me what I am missing or what I'm doing wrong I'd be very thankful for it!

PS: the table is shown and its working fine with the implement the repeat but only the sorting doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Angular ng-table dynamic headers doesn't work inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627714/angular-ng-table-dynamic-headers-doesnt-work-inside)

as the answer there says "Define a template for a header, and set a template-header attribute of ng-table."

Answer (score 3):

You are not setting correct values on your sortable attribute.

The attribute expects a model that represents a string.

Try:

```
    <div ng-controller="tbleCtrl">
  <table ng-table show-filter="true" class="floodPostTable">    
    <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
        <td sortable="'number'" data-title="'Number'"><div ng-show="item.number != false">{{ item.number }}</div></td>
        <td sortable="'roadNumber'" data-title="'Road Number'"><div ng-show="item.roadNumber != false">{{ item.roadNumber }}</div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

You'll notice I removed your th elements, ng-table will create them for you.

You're also missing the use of an actual ngTableParams instance and the setting of it as the value on ng-table attribute. Not sure how you intend to actually show any rows without doing what ngTable pretty much requires you to do.

Try a look here: http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/1

Comment: you noticed that the `item` obj is defined ***after*** the `<th>` ? so how can I do it ?

Comment: thanks @SirDemon, i've tried this one already .. (I didnt have much luck) as the table doesn't get sorted (on click) just the arrows near the title changes ... but anyway an answer with keeping the `<th>` will be better as it part of my table design .. (css)ed

Comment: Passing to sortable as a string is surprisingly easy to miss, I spent quite a while looking at more complex solutions and this answer made me spot I was missing the single quotes...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 
`<tr ng-repeat="item in data">`

try

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in $data">
```