# ng-table-dynamic sorting does not work for dynamic columns

Tags: angularjs, sorting, ngtable

I am trying to use ng-table-dynamic, sorting does not work.
I have cols and rows in the scope and the data is displayed correctly, I can see the sorting icons but on clicking them the data does not sort.

```
<table ng-table-dynamic="tableParams with cols" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
  <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <td ng-repeat="col in cols">
      <div ng-if="row[col.field]['value']" style="color:{{row[col.field]['color']}}">{{row[col.field]['value']}}</div>
      <div ng-if="!row[col.field]['value']">{{row[col.field]}} </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please see this [codepen](http://codepen.io/prajaktah/pen/bpYeQQ?editors=1010)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627714/angular-ng-table-dynamic-headers-doesnt-work-inside This link might help you!

Answer (score 0):

Worked after I edited the code. I did not understand how ng-table-dynamic works before, thanks Danda!

```
<table ng-table-dynamic="tableParams with cols" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
  <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
    <td ng-repeat="col in $columns">
      <div ng-if="row[col.field]['value']" style="color:{{row[col.field]['color']}}">{{row[col.field]['value']}}</div>
      <div ng-if="!row[col.field]['value']">{{row[col.field]}} </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```